# How does one distribute a node js app without making it open source?

Tags: node.js, binaryfiles, software-distribution, serverside-javascript, on-premises-instances

The question is not about client side exposure of code - I clearly understand the distinction  between client side and server side code in Node js. The question is about packing and distribution of Node js app like an enterprise application made with languages like C#, Java - will the server side code be always available to the enterprise or person the application is provided for on-premise installation. **Is there a way to package and restrict the code visibility (server side code) for Node js applications?**

Comment: This might help - https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: While this is a valid response to my question, it still remains un-feasible since enterprise solutions that are deployed on premise require horizontal and vertical scaling and be optimized as web application which is not the case for Electron apps.